# Can anybody tell me what d = d+1 and l = l+1 do in this code what its uses in this code?

Tags: python

In this code first it take d=0 and l = 0 and then it write d=d+1 and l=l+1 do in this code what its uses in this code ? ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uw5q.png)

In this code first it take d=0 and l = 0 and then it write d=d+1 and l=l+1 do in this code what its uses in this code ?

Comment: n = input()
l = 0
d = 0
for i in n:
    if i.isdigit():
        d =d+1
    elif i.isalpha():
        l = l+1
    else:
        break
print("letter",l,"digit",d)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: When the site told you your question didn't have enough detail to be posted, the correct thing to do **wasn't** to just repeat the one sentence you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through it line by line - first you run a loop where each character of the input is sequentially represented as `i`.

Now, for each `i`, if `i` is a digit, you increase the count of `d` - using `d=d+1`.
Otherwise (`elif`) if `i` is an alphabet, you increase the count of `l` - using `l=l+1`.

This way you're storing the number of digits in the input as `d`, and the number of letters in the input as `l`.

Finally, after the loop runs on all character of the input, you print the number of letters and digits respectively using `print("letter",l,"digit",d)`